# Html textarea isn't up-to-date on jquery keypress

Tags: javascript, html, forms, textarea

I have a bunch of forms on a page that each contain an html textarea:

```
<textarea name="Comment" class="inputTextArea">Hello World!</textarea>
```

I have javascript event handler that submits the form when the user presses Enter:

```
$(".inputTextArea").keypress(function (e) {
    if (e.which === 13 && !e.shiftKey) {
        $(this).closest("form").submit();
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

The javascript does submit the form on Enter, but the submitted data does not contain the current contents of the textarea.

If I set a breakpoint on the call to submit() and look at the contents of "this" (which is the textarea), the innerHTML shows the *initial* textarea's contents (i.e., "Hello World!") rather than the text that is currently in the textarea (e.g., "Goodbye World!").

Is there something I need to do to update the textarea control's contents before submitting it?

Thanks!

**SOLUTION (or "CAUSE" or "<blush>")**

My forms have two submit buttons, so my call to $(this).closest("form").submit() wasn't selecting the button I expected (a "Save" button). When the form was posted, I wasn't saving the posted data and thought the textarea hadn't been updated—that wasn't the case.

My solution was to make sure the correct button was clicked when Enter was pressed.

```
var buttons = $(this).closest('form').find(':submit');
buttons[0].click();
```

Embarrassingly, this topic, and its title, have nothing to do with the problem or solution, but maybe my clumsy path to a solution will help someone else.

Comment: Typing in a textarea doesn't change `.innerHTML`, it changes `.value`.  You don't have to update the contents, you should just be able to submit it.

Comment: James, knowing that the .value, not the .innerHTML, changed quickly exposed the problem (i.e., I could see that the .value **had** changed).

Answer (score 1):

In the provided code it should work perfectly, the issue might be in form

```js
$(".inputTextArea").keypress(function (e) {
    if (e.which === 13 && !e.shiftKey) {
        $(this).closest("form").submit();
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<form >
<textarea name="Comment" class="inputTextArea">Hello World!</textarea>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary submit-btn">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Yes, Adeeb, the issue was in the form. I had two submit buttons. I edited my initial post to expose the problem.